# Are Puppeteer's page.metrics() *Duration values measured in seconds or milliseconds?

Tags: puppeteer, chromium, chrome-devtools-protocol

I assume these `*Duration` variables are measured in seconds or milliseconds, but I'm having trouble finding confirmation in [Puppeteer](https://pptr.dev/#?product=Puppeteer&version=main&show=api-pagemetrics)/[Chromium](https://source.chromium.org/chromium)/[DevTools Protocol](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Performance/#type-Metric) documentation.

Example metrics object:

```
Documents:3
Frames:3
JSEventListeners:279
JSHeapTotalSize:8450048
JSHeapUsedSize:6831380
LayoutCount:46
LayoutDuration:0.11537
Nodes:1768
RecalcStyleCount:222
RecalcStyleDuration:0.047973
ScriptDuration:4.339174
TaskDuration:4.863449
Timestamp:42554.544667
```

Answer (score 0):

While writing this question I studied Chromium's [code search filters](https://developers.google.com/code-search/reference) some more and [found the answer](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:third_party/blink/renderer/core/inspector/inspector_performance_agent.cc;l=207-209,220,231?q=Metrics%20AND%20LayoutDuration%20lang:cpp&ss=chromium).

```cc
// Page performance metrics.
...
AppendMetric(result.get(), "LayoutDuration", layout_duration_.InSecondsF());
AppendMetric(result.get(), "RecalcStyleDuration",
             recalc_style_duration_.InSecondsF());
...
AppendMetric(result.get(), "ScriptDuration", script_duration.InSecondsF());
...
AppendMetric(result.get(), "TaskDuration", task_duration.InSecondsF());
```

Every duration metric is transformed with [`InSecondsF`](https://source.chromium.org/chromium/chromium/src/+/main:base/time/time.h;l=943) (i.e. every *Duration metric is measured in **seconds**).